# Ошибка при попытке вывести первую букву слова в заглавном и остаток слова в строчном виде

Tags: c#, строки

Выдает ошибку System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. "

суть задания:
string UpdateWords (string data) – Данный метод производит удаление всех лишних пробелов в строке data и преобразует первую букву каждого слова к верхнему регистру.
Создать текстовый файл test.txt с 20 исходными данными для проверки работы метода.

```
public class REG_MARK
    {
        public string UpdateWords (string data)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] stringArray = s.Split(" ");

            for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
            {
                return(stringArray[i].Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + stringArray[i].Substring(1));
            }

            return " ";
        }
==========================================================
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            REG_MARK r = new REG_MARK();

            string data = @"C:\test.txt";

            r.UpdateWords(data);
        }
```

Comment: Вы забыли принять ответ на ваш прошлый вопрос. И без входных данных тут мало чего можно понять. Попробуйте `s.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Еще вы забыли файл закрыть, читайте его так `string s = File.ReadAllText(data);`.

Comment: не помогло. ошибки не возникает, но консоль после выполнения пустая

Comment: хотя если создать отдельную строку переменную куда и будет записываться значение изменненое и вернуть ее, то все равно выводит пустоту, хотя значение в данной переменной имеется
`string updated = stringArray[i].Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + stringArray[i].Substring(1);
                return (updated);`
@aepot

Comment: Наверное потому что вы в первой же итерации цикла return делаете? Отлаживайте код, выполняйте пошагово. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Comment: благодарю за помощь